# How to properly move a React Native project to a new directory?

Tags: android, react-native

Whenever I move my React Native projects they never seem to work in the new directory. I am using `npx react-native run-android` to run but the build always fails. This time I am getting :mergeDexDebug FAILED even though I have enabled multiDex. So, how should I move the project to a new directory?

Answer (score 1):

You could upload it to github, delete where it is on your local device, then git clone it in the place that you want.

Comment: I had to run `npm install` and because the project was raw, I had to also run `cd ios && pod install`